# What are the unbox rates for the new Weapon Cases?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I attempted at one point to unbox a new Weapon Case in TF2, but I had mixed opinions about doing so in the first place and I didn't end up with a desirable item. So that got me thinking.

**What exactly are the percentage probabilities of getting a Strange or Unusual skin, or a higher-tier skin from the specific case's collection in better condition?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct about the weapon rates. I couldn't find any data about skin quality rates or Strange/Strange Unusual rates and they likely aren't known. We can speculate that the Strange drop rate is about the same as the Strange drop rate for Festive weapons, but I couldn't find any hard numbers for those either. People like to pin it around 10-20% but that's just a guess. Unfortunately, we're not likely to get a whole lot of new insight on it. Presumably, the rate for a Strange Unusual weapon would be the `Strange chance * Unusual chance`, which would put it around 0.1-0.2%.

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to power house and concealed killer cases. then you have 6.60% of chances in acquiring any of the weapon listed on the case. and a 1% chance of it being unussual

Comment: "6.60% chance" is outright wrong as not all the weapons have the same rarity.

Comment: they do infact,.. and its a clever lottery math<br>
lets use concealer case as example<br>
<br>
 theres only 2 of 6.60% to get a elite but theres a variety of percentage of getting a certain skin condition(which affects its market price greately). then theres SIX mercenary grade which ofc have 6.60% chances each, ... its pretty much answers why mercenary grade has higher chance of being drawn. since in the end... they had the larger quantity in a case

Answer (score -1):

- Turbine Torcher Flame Thrower (16%)
- Low Profile SMG (16%)
- Aqua Marine Rocket Launcher (16%)
- Brick House Minigun (16%)
- Lightning Rod Shotgun (16%)
- Sandstone Special Pistol (3.2%)
- Black Dahlia Pistol (3.2%)
- Dead Reckoner Revolver (3.2%)
- Spark of Life Medi Gun (3.2%)
- Flash Fryer Flame Thrower (3.2%)
- Pink Elephant Stickybomb Launcher (1.06%)
- Current Event Scattergun (1.06%)
- Shell Shocker Rocket Launcher (1.06%)
- Liquid Asset Stickybomb Launcher (0.04%)
- Thunderbolt Sniper Rifle (0.04%)

Comment: You sure have given a lot of exact numbers. You might want to provide the source, as some will down vote this off face value.